# Meaning of 'staging' in 'the Qur'an's staging, penetrating and eclipsing of Biblical tradition'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, ambiguity, religion

What's the meaning of the word *staging* in the following context?

"The Qurʾān’s **Staging**, Penetrating and Eclipsing of Biblical Tradition"

It's the address of a study conducted by Angelika Neuwirth.

Comment: A little unclear, without more context, but "staging" tends to be used in the sense of preparing a theater production, though sometimes in the sense of "faking".

Comment: The author isn't a native Anglophone anyway. Personally I don't understand exactly what she means by metaphoric ***penetrating*** and ***eclipsing*** here either, so it may not mean much at all to ask what she wants us to understand from these words.

Comment: By *address*, do you mean the paper's title? Did you get a chance yet to read the study?   A title sometimes leaves a bit of mystery to draw the reader in, like a newspaper headline. Could she mean the Quran reframed and rearranged earlier tradition?

Comment: Possibly Neuwirth meant _upstaging_...? That works with the rest of the context.